# PHP money_format: Removing decimals based on value

Tags: php, currency, money-format

I've got a value that I wish to display in a specific format.

I want the price to be either 895,25 (if there is a decimal value), or 895,- if there is no decimal value (00).

Here is my code:

```
money_format('%!n', '895,00')
```

The above outputs:

```
895,00
```

I tried the following but with no luck, it simply removes the value.

```
money_format('%!.0n', '895.25');
```

Turns into this:

```
895
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this: `str_ireplace(",00", ",-", money_format('%!n', '895,00'))`?

Comment: I haven't tried str_replace. I was kindda hoping I was overlooking something in the money_format method

Answer (score 0):

you could make the precision adaptive as:

```
function mfmt($val){
    $prec = 2;
    $suffix = "";
    if(round($val, 0) == $val){
        $prec = 0;
        $suffix = ",-";
    }
    return money_format("%!.${prec}n${suffix}", $val);
}

echo mfmt(825.25)."\n"; //825.25
echo mfmt(825)."\n"; //825,-
```